# Read C output in Python

Tags: python, c

I'm building a logger to measure temperature and humidity. It's my first Raspberry Pi project.

I followed these [instructions](http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Temperature-Humidity-Network-Monitor/?ALLSTEPS). The logger runs fine, but I would like to do some things a little differently.

The C program reads the sensor and writes the values to a MySQL database. It is also responsible for the interval. I would like the C program to read the sensor and return the values. Nothing more. This way I can read the sensor from various applications. So I stripped the [WiringPi](http://wiringpi.com) example code down to this:

```
/* File: thck.c */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <maxdetect.h>

#define    RHT03_PIN    7

int main (void)
{
  int result, temperature, relativeHumidity ;
  wiringPiSetup () ;
  piHiPri       (55) ;

  for (;;)
  {
    delay (50) ;

    result = readRHT03 (RHT03_PIN, &temperature, &relativeHumidity) ;

    if(result && temperature != 0 &&  relativeHumidity != 0)
    {
       printf("%2.1f %2.1f", temperature / 10.0, relativeHumidity / 10.0) ;
       break ;
    }
  }
  return 0 ;
}
```

In Python I tried to read the output. It prints a string with the temperature and humidity values, but the returned value is `0`:

```
>>> from subprocess import call
>>> call('./th')
17.5 52.1
>>> foo = call('./th')
17.5 52.1>>> foo
0
>>>
```

How do I change the C program so it's returned value is `'17.5 52.1'` and not `0`?

Comment: You can't.  A C program (a program in any language) returns an integer status.  You want to change the Python program so it gets the stdout (printf) of the C program rather than the status of the C program.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: [Retrieving the output of subprocess.call()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996518/retrieving-the-output-of-subprocess-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of @joan:

> You can't. A C program (a program in any language) returns an integer status. You want to change the Python program so it gets the stdout (printf) of the C program rather than the status of the C program.

I do this in Python:

```
>>> from subprocess import check_output
>>> foo = check_output('./th', shell=True)
>>> foo
'17.9 51.0'
```

Comment: If this is the solution to your problem could you please mark it as correct.